# PDO bindparam empty values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When executing a PDO bindParam call the values being inserted into the DB are empty.

Looking at the log the parameters don't appear to be transmitting

```
Prepare     INSERT INTO StockItemTypes SET  Name = ?, PartNumber = ?, BarCodeNumber = ?, LeadTimeWeeks = ?,  PriceGroupFK = ?, MinimumOrderQuantity = ?, ReorderPointOverride = ?,  MinimumStockLevelOverride = ?, CurrentQuantity = ?, ApplianceTypeFK = ?,  Rack = ?, Shelf = ?
Execute     INSERT INTO StockItemTypes SET  Name = '', PartNumber = '', BarCodeNumber = '', LeadTimeWeeks = '',  PriceGroupFK = '', MinimumOrderQuantity = '', ReorderPointOverride = '',  MinimumStockLevelOverride = '', CurrentQuantity = '', ApplianceTypeFK = '',  Rack = '', Shelf = ''
```

The database is managed by a class that is known to work and does work on other areas of the site.

I have also created a getQuery method on the class and when viewing that I get the SET commands present, but this just outputs what would be ran for debug purposes.

I can't see any issues and no errors are triggered, any ideas?

Insert Code

```
$query = "INSERT INTO StockItemTypes SET " . 
    " Name = :P_Name, PartNumber = :P_PartNumber, BarCodeNumber = :P_BarCodeNumber, LeadTimeWeeks = :P_LeadTimeWeeks, " . 
    " PriceGroupFK = :P_PriceGroup, MinimumOrderQuantity = :P_MinOrderQty, ReorderPointOverride = :P_ReorderPointOverride, " . 
    " MinimumStockLevelOverride = :P_MinimumStockLevelOverride, CurrentQuantity = :P_CurrentQuantity, ApplianceTypeFK = :P_ApplianceType, " . 
    " Rack = :P_Rack, Shelf = :P_Shelf;";

$dbpars = parent::$DB->NewParamList();
parent::$DB->addParam($dbpars, ':P_Name', $StockItemName);
parent::$DB->addParam($dbpars, ':P_PartNumber', $PartNumber);
parent::$DB->addParam($dbpars, ':P_BarCodeNumber', $Barcode);
parent::$DB->addParam($dbpars, ':P_LeadTimeWeeks', $LeadTime);
parent::$DB->addParam($dbpars, ':P_PriceGroup', $PriceGroup);
parent::$DB->addParam($dbpars, ':P_MinOrderQty', $MinOrderQTY);
parent::$DB->addParam($dbpars, ':P_ReorderPointOverride', $NewReOrderQTY);
parent::$DB->addParam($dbpars, ':P_MinimumStockLevelOverride', $MinStockLevelOverride);
parent::$DB->addParam($dbpars, ':P_CurrentQuantity', $CurrentStockQTY);
parent::$DB->addParam($dbpars, ':P_ApplianceType', $ApplianceType);
parent::$DB->addParam($dbpars, ':P_Rack', $Rack);
parent::$DB->addParam($dbpars, ':P_Shelf', $Shelf);

parent::$DB->Run($query, $dbpars);
```

DB Class

```
    public function Connect()
    {
        try 
        {
            $t = array(
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, 
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, 
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true
            );

            $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME . ';charset=utf8', DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, $t);
            unset($t);
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            $this->Error($ex->getMessage(), 'Connection', $ex->getFile(), $ex->getLine(), $ex->getTraceAsString());
        }
    }

    public function Run($QUERY, $PARAMS = array())
    {

        $this->Connect();

        try 
        {
            $sql = $this->db->prepare($QUERY);

            if (count($PARAMS) > 0)
            {   
                foreach ($PARAMS as $KEY=>$VAL)
                {
                    $sql->bindParam(str_replace(":", "", $KEY), $VAL);
                }
            }

            $sql->execute();
            $this->SQLErrorInfo = $sql->errorInfo();

        }
        catch (Exception $ex)
        {
            $this->Error($ex->getMessage(), $QUERY, $ex->getFile(), $ex->getLine(), $ex->getTraceAsString());
            $this->SQLErrorCode = $sql->errorCode();
            $this->SQLErrorInfo = $sql->errorInfo();
            exit();
        }
        if (!$sql)
        {
            //fatal error
            $ex = $sql->errorInfo();
            $this->Error($ex[2], $QUERY, __FILE__, __LINE__, print_r(debug_backtrace(), true));
            exit();
        } 

        $this->last_insert_id = $this->db->lastInsertId();
        $this->affected_rows = $sql->rowCount();

        return $sql;//retval
    }

    public function addParam(&$PARAMLIST, $PARCODE, $VAL)
    {
        $PARAMLIST[$PARCODE] = $VAL;
    }

    public function getQuery($QUERY, $PARAMLIST)
    {
        $retval = '/* params */' . "\n";
        if (count($PARAMLIST) > 0)
        {
            foreach ($PARAMLIST as $key=>$val)
            {
                $newkey = str_replace(":", "", $key);
                $retval .= 'SET @'. $newkey . ' = "' . $val . '";' . "\n";
                $QUERY = str_replace($key, "@".$newkey, $QUERY);
            }
        }
        $retval .= "\n" . '/* Query */' . "\n" . $QUERY;
        return $retval;
    }
```

Result of getQuery call showing the variables are set

```
/* params */
SET @P_Name = "test";
SET @P_PartNumber = "test";
SET @P_BarCodeNumber = "test";
SET @P_LeadTimeWeeks = "1";
SET @P_PriceGroup = "1";
SET @P_MinOrderQty = "0";
SET @P_ReorderPointOverride = "1";
SET @P_MinimumStockLevelOverride = "0";
SET @P_CurrentQuantity = "1";
SET @P_ApplianceType = "2";
SET @P_Rack = "";
SET @P_Shelf = "";

/* Query */
INSERT INTO StockItemTypes SET  Name = @P_Name, PartNumber = @P_PartNumber, BarCodeNumber = @P_BarCodeNumber, LeadTimeWeeks = @P_LeadTimeWeeks,  PriceGroupFK = @P_PriceGroup, MinimumOrderQuantity = @P_MinOrderQty, ReorderPointOverride = @P_ReorderPointOverride,  MinimumStockLevelOverride = @P_MinimumStockLevelOverride, CurrentQuantity = @P_CurrentQuantity, ApplianceTypeFK = @P_ApplianceType,  Rack = @P_Rack, Shelf = @P_Shelf;
```

running the above inserts the data into the DB indicating the issue is somewhere in PDO.

Comment: Why not extend `PDOStatement`? I mean, having to parse `$dbpars` everytime seems deficient.

Comment: Also you should `PDO::quote()` the `$val` in the `$retval` assignment.

Comment: @Xorifelse on what method should I be using the PDO::quote() ?

Comment: `$retval .= 'SET @'. $newkey . ' = "' . $this->db->quote($val) . '";' . "\n";`, if you don't try adding a `"` as 1 of the values and you will see why.

Comment: @Xorifelse thanks for that I'll get that added in

Answer (score 2):

`bindParam` binds to a reference to the variable, so you're binding all your parameters to the same variable `$VAL`, and they're all getting the last value of the variable.

Your database class should use `bindVal` rather than `bindParam`. This binds to the variable's current value, not its value when the `execute()` call is made.

I'm not really sure why you're doing all this complicated stuff. You're basically replicating what `execute()` does when it's given an array as an argument, automatically binding all the parameters from that array. You can just do that in your function.

```
public function Run($QUERY, $PARAMS = array())
{

    $this->Connect();

    try 
    {
        $sql = $this->db->prepare($QUERY);

        $sql->execute($PARAMS);
        $this->SQLErrorInfo = $sql->errorInfo();

    }
    catch (Exception $ex)
    {
        $this->Error($ex->getMessage(), $QUERY, $ex->getFile(), $ex->getLine(), $ex->getTraceAsString());
        $this->SQLErrorCode = $sql->errorCode();
        $this->SQLErrorInfo = $sql->errorInfo();
        exit();
    }
    if (!$sql)
    {
        //fatal error
        $ex = $sql->errorInfo();
        $this->Error($ex[2], $QUERY, __FILE__, __LINE__, print_r(debug_backtrace(), true));
        exit();
    } 

    $this->last_insert_id = $this->db->lastInsertId();
    $this->affected_rows = $sql->rowCount();

    return $sql;//retval
}
```

It's also not necessary to remove `:` from `$KEY`.

Comment: this doesn't explain why the same system works elsewhere on the same site with multiple parameters?  Originally bindVal didn't work in the call but bindParam did on earlier versions of php, I'll try swapping back see if this has any adverse affects

Comment: I can't explain that, it looks to me like it should never work.

Comment: Switching to bindVal has corrected this issue, doesn't explain why bindParam works everywhere else but I'll mark this as the accepted answer

Comment: I really suggest you just use `execute($PARAMS);`. You're just duplicating what that does.

Comment: The other developers that use this come from a non PDO environment so they found it is easier this way

Comment: Why do they care about the implementation of the class? They're just using it.